# Was darf nach dem Wort »Anzahl« stehen?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

Insbesondere geht es um folgende Konstruktion:

> [...], denen man eine beliebige Anzahl Elemente übergeben kann.

Ist das so in Ordnung? Was die Alternativen betrifft:

- beliebige Anzahl an Elementen
- beliebige Anzahl von Elementen

Weiß jemand, ob es einen – wenn auch nur geschichtlichen – Unterschied zwischen diesen gibt?

Comment: Geht alles, aber warum nicht einfach: _beliebig viele Elemente_?

Comment: Was genau ist die Frage? Willst du wissen, wie man das Wort »Anzahl« verwenden kann (so steht es in der Überschrift), oder willst du wissen, welche Unterschiede es zwischen den Verwendungsmöglichkeiten gibt (das Fragst du am Ende des Fließtextes)? Das sind nämlich zwei unterschiedliche Fragen. Man sollte aber pro Posting wenn möglich nur eine Frage stellen.

Comment: @Crissov Weil ich auch diese Konstruktion selbstsicher verwenden können möchte  :)

Comment: @Grantwalzer: Das kann man auch höflicher sagen.

Answer (score 1):

Der Satz

> [...], denen man eine beliebige Anzahl Elemente übergeben kann.

ist völlig in Ordnung.

Laut einem [Beispiels des Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Anzahl#Bedeutunga) ist die Kombination mit „von“ richtig:

> eine ganze Anzahl Kinder/von Kindern kam/(seltener:) kamen uns entgegen

<del>Wie es mit „an“ aussieht, kann ich nicht sagen. Ich konnte zumindest nirgendwo etwas finden, wo die Präposition „an“ benutzt wird.</del>

Nachtrag: [@Em1](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/1224) hat einen Eintrag im Duden gefunden, in dem „Anzahl *an* [...]“ benutzt wird. Siehe dazu [diesen Kommentar](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/23350/23364#comment53084_23364).

Comment: Im Duden unter [isoster](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/isoster) befindet sich das Beispiel "die gleiche Anzahl an Elektronen besitzend"