# Reihe von Institutionen oder Reihe an Institutionen?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, preposition

Ist dieser Satz richtig?

> Da weltweit sichergestellt sein muss, dass jede IP-Adresse nur einmal verwendet wird, gibt es eine Reihe **an** Institutionen, die dies sicherstellen.

Oder muss *an* durch *von* ersetzt werden?

Comment: related: http://german.stackexchange.com/q/23350/1224

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wir unterscheiden bei Mengenangaben zwei Fälle:

**a) bestimmte (wenn auch unbekannte) Anzahl Objekte oder Menge von etwas Greifbarem**

> die doppelte Menge [an] Milch
>
> eine Reihe [an] Institutionen
>
> *Guten Tag, haben Sie heute etwas Neues an Münzen?* (Frage eines Antiquitätengeschäftskunden)

**b) große, unbestimmte Anzahl Objekte**

> Da liegt eine Menge faule Äpfel / fauler Äpfel / von faulen Äpfeln.
>
> Eine Menge Leute kam / kamen zusammen. **aber** Eine Menge von Leuten kam zusammen.

Für Dinge, die man nicht zählen kann und die nicht greifbar sind, benutzen wir die Version ohne Präposition und ohne Artikel.

> Du hast dir eine Menge Ärger eingehandelt, junger Mann.

Um auf die konkrete Frage näher einzugehen:

> *eine Reihe an Institutionen* --> es gibt viele Institutionen und eine (relative) kleine Anzahl davon befasst sich mit der Sicherstellung der IP-Adressen.
>
> *eine Reihe [von] Institutionen* --> es gibt viele Institutionen, die sich mit der Sicherstellung befassen.

Es muss unbedingt hinzugefügt werden, dass es oft schwierig ist, eine klare Grenze zwischen den beiden Anwendungsfällen zu ziehen und es ist oft weitestgehend Geschmackssache / sprachliche Gewohnheit, welche Form benutzt wird. Dennoch gibt es gewisse Tendenzen und linguistische Nuancen bei der Verwendung von *an / von* bei Mengenangaben, die aber nicht immer so einfach zu beschreiben sind.

[Quelle](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Menge)

Answer (score 1):

Richtig ist

> eine Reihe von Institutionen

Ich habe als Muttersprachler nach Bauchgefühl entschieden.
Ich habe aber nochmal [hier](https://blog.canoonet.eu/2011/06/15/eine-menge-schwarze-schafe/) die Regel dazu rausgesucht. Das *von* stimmt, da „Institutionen“ ein Sammelbegriff ist.