# »Anzahl verteilte Aufträge« vs. »Anzahl verteilter Aufträge«

Tags: phrase, grammatical-case

Ich möchte Kennzahlen benennen und kann mich leider nicht zwischen Folgenden entscheiden:

> Anzahl verteilte Aufträge
>
> Anzahl verteilte**r** Aufträge

Was ist denn nun richtig? Etwa beides? Besonders verwirrend ist für mich, dass ich intuitiv (hoffentlich falsch) zwei Kennzahlen einmal »Anzahl verteilte Aufträge« und »Anzahl direkt verteilte**r** Aufträge« genannt habe. Macht das Adverb hier den Unterschied oder muss eigentlich beides gleich *verteilte* oder *verteilte**r*** heißen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Anzahl verteilte Aufträge" ist in meinen Augen/Ohren richtig. Aber nur als Kennzahl-Benennung. Ansonsten hängt es vom Kontext ab. Z.B.: Wie groß ist denn nun die Anzahl verteilter Aufträge?

Als Kennzahl sieht die Sache anders aus. Das Wort Anzahl gruppiert die Kennzahl in eine "Kategorie" (eine andere Kategorie könnte z.B. Betrag sein, oder Größe) während "verteilte Aufträge" eine Art Subjekt darstellt. Somit würde ich "verteilte Aufträge" losgelöst von Anzahl betrachten. Und hat man nur diesen Begriff, hört sich "verteilter Aufträge" falsch an.

Comment: Vielen Dank für die hilfreichen Antworten und auch die Umformulierung meiner Frage zur richtigen grammatikalischen Einordnung. Ich werde jetzt bei den Kennzahlen einheitlich auf die Deklinierung also das "r" am Ende verzichten und das bei allen Kennzahlen einheitlich machen.

Answer (score 8):

Grammatikalisch korrekt ist es, das Adjektiv mit dem Genitiv zu deklinieren:

> Die Anzahl verteilter Aufträge ist abhängig vom Mitarbeiter.
>   Die Anzahl dicker Kinder hat in den letzen 20 Jahren zugenommen.

Nur, wenn man die zu zählende Kenngröße als eine Bezeichnung auffasst, kann man in einer Tabelle oder mit Stichworten darauf verzichten:

> Anzahl *verteilte Aufträge: 20*
>   Anzahl *dicke Kinder: 15*

Je mehr die Stichworte Satzcharakter erhalten, desto weniger wird man auf eine Deklination verzichten. Genau das ist durch das Einfügen von *direkt* in Deinem Beispiel passiert:

> *Anzahl direkt verteilter Aufträge*

Auch dort hätte man natürlich auch *Anzahl direkt verteilte Aufträge* sagen können, denn beides ist in einer Tabelle oder in Stichworten richtig.

Auch wenn die *Anzahl* als unbestimmte (nicht gezählte) Größe verwendet wird ist eine undeklinierte Verwendung möglich. Siehe auch: [Reihe von Institutionen oder Reihe an Institutionen?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/24708/reihe-von-institutionen-oder-reihe-an-institutionen)

Comment: Verwendet man "Anzahl" als eine nicht definierte Maßangabe, darf man es mMn durchaus im Nominativ nehmen - *Auf der Lichtung sah ich eine große Anzahl junge Hirsche" wie im Sinne von "ein Glas Milch" oder "ein Liter Wasser", wo man auch nicht (mehr) den Genitiv nimmt.

Comment: @tofro: gute Ergänzung, Danke.